# Can't send tweets with python using Twitter API (foreign letters)

Tags: python, twitter

Sooo yeah, pretty much what the title says. Can't seem to tweet foreign letter's to twitter, not quite sure why though, so i'm hoping if anybody can help me there. The foreign letters are "õüöä" Here is my .py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tweepy, time, sys

argfile = str(sys.argv[1])

#API details
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'xx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xx'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

str.decode('utf-8')
filename=open(argfile,'r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()

for line in f:
api.update_status(line)
time.sleep(120)
```

My .txt file where tweets are included:

```
Üks
Kaks
Kolm
Neli
Viis
Kuus
Seitse
Kaheksa
Üheksa
Kümme
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  A) you're missing an indent for api.update_status(line) B) Part of asking includes what exception/behavior you get, which might help.  Also, are you using python2 or python3, as that may matter regarding handling unicode.  (Also, calling your file handle filename is confusing but that's minor)

Comment: Hey thanks for quick reply, i am using python 3

Comment: Fixed it, just had to remove "str.decode('utf-8')" mod can close